# How to get returning associative array element from function?

Tags: php

```
public function getPhotos($id_album){
$hisPhoto = '123';
$myPhoto = '456';
$herPhoto = '789';
$id_user = 1;
$photoTable = array
(
    'hisPhoto' => $hisPhoto,
    'myPhoto' => $myPhoto,
    'herPhoto' => $herPhoto,
);

return array
(
    'id_user' => $id_user,
    'photos' => $photoTable
)
}

$photos = getPhotos($id_album);
```

I have no idea how to use associative array in associative array.
What is the simplest way using this function to get to the my photo (value '456')?

Comment: I have no idea what your current output is and what you expect! Please make a example (See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In short: "it is unclear what you ask"

Comment: @Michoser I still don't get it. What is your question/problem? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$photos` will end up having the structure:

```
Array
(

'id_user' => $id_user,

'photos' => 
          Array
              (
                'hisPhoto' => $hisPhoto,
                'myPhoto' => $myPhoto,
                'herPhoto' => $herPhoto
              )
)
```

So you can just go:

```
echo $photos['photos']['myPhoto'];
```

If you are stuck with the structure of an array you can use:

```
print_r($array);
```

To view the structure